# Adding a conan generated CMake variable to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in test_package recipe

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

OK, so the package I am working on is built and ready, however when the test_package calls the test() method in the azure pipeline, it fails at runtime with the usual:

```
./example: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This library is in a path which is part of another dependent package. I want to add the CONAN_LIB_DIRS_XXXXX cmake variable to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But that is not accessible in the test_package conanfile.py recipe. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can change the `test_package/CMakeLists.txt`, by adding `target_link_directories`. Anyway, a Conan package should enough by itself, if something is missing, then the package is broken/bugged. The correct approach is fixing the package. If that package is from Conan Center, you can open an issue to https://conan-io/conan-center-index/issues

Comment: It could also be that is necessary to use the ``self.run(..., run_environment=True)`` to automatically enable the environment (including the LD_LIBRARY_PATH). But it sounds a bit weird, because usually the ``test_package`` is built locally, and that might be good enough to locate the shared lib (depending on RPATHs management). If necessary it might be good to submit a reproducible example to Conan issues (if not a ConanCenter package)